# VPN me crea subredes

Tags: redes, vpn

Buenos días, estoy instalando un servidor VPN de tal forma que tengo dos máquinas virtuales, una de ella tiene el servicio OpenVPN y la otra tiene un servicio Apache corriendo, ambas máquinas se encuentran en el mismo segmento de red 10.8.0.1 (VPN) y 10.8.0.3 (Apache) la máquina virtual de Apache no tiene acceso a Internet mientras que VPN si, disponemos de una dirección estática y un puerto redirigido en el Router.

Esta es nuestra configuración del fichero server.conf:

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/vpn.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/vpn.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.1.220 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb1
```

A la hora de establecer conexión con VPN desde el cliente, ya sea Windows o OSx se nos conecta perfectamente, incluso navega en internet desde esta nueva IP pública, pero sin embargo es incapaz de hacer un ping con la máquina que tiene Apache y que gracias al VPN ya se encuentra dentro de su propia red. Es como si OpenVPN cada vez que alguien se conecta hiciera pequeñas subredes, ya que la mácara de red que asigna al cliente siempre es 255.255.255.252

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar un `ip route list` de tu máquina una vez establecido el túnel? Que se creen pequeñas subredes es normal, pero el `client-to-client` te permitiría comunicarte entre clientes del VPN directamente sin pasar por `iptables` y si no repites red también con los servidores que estén dentro de la red `10.8.0.0`. ¿La máquina `10.8.0.3` qué tiene configurado como puerta de enlace? ¿Qué IP tiene tu máquina dentro de la VPN?

Comment: el resultado de ip route list --
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 onlink -- 10.8.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2 -- 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scape link src 10.8.0.1 -- 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.220 -- y la máquina 10.8.0.3 tiene como puerta de enlace 10.8.0.1

Comment: Estoy presuponiendo en mi respuesta que has usado el mismo direccionamiento para tu LAN que para las IPs de la VPN. Te recomiendo cambiarlo y separar el direccionamiento de VPN del direccionamiento de LAN tal y como te muestro (por poner un ejemplo). También debes vigilar que la máquina Apache sepa cómo enviar los paquetes de vuelta cuando no tienes configurada puerta de enlace en la máquina mediante rutas estáticas.

Comment: Por cierto @Ramón, ¿ese es el resultado en la máquina cliente o en el servidor? ¿No te salen las rutas a la LAN?

Comment: Un apunte, la máquina que está trabajando Apache, no está conectada al VPN, ya que pertenece a la misma red que él

Comment: Precisamente ese es el problema, no puedes asignar IPs en la VPN a IPs del rango de la LAN. Debes crear dos redes separadas. Por ejemplo que el Apache y el servidor VPN tengan IPs de LAN `10.8.0.1-3` pero que la VPN ofrezca IPs del rango `10.9.0.x`.

Comment: Voy a escribir una respuesta más simplificada y concisa sin aclarar ni diluirse en los diferentes escenarios en los que te puedes encontrar.

Comment: Ya he hecho el cambio a mi respuesta, prueba y me cuentas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Descripción

Los problemas principales que sufres son dos:

- Usar el mismo rango de IPs para la LAN que para los clientes VPN.
- Tener activa la opción `client-to-client` impidiendo salir del servidor openvpn los paquetes que vayan como destino al rango de IPs de la VPN.

## Solución propuesta (1)

Te propondría cambiar la topología de red de [net30](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Topology#Topologynet30) a [subred](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Topology#Topologysubnet) para facilitar la gestión, pero si no quieres hacer muchos cambios te propongo sólo el siguiente:

```
server 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2
```

De esta manera la VPN asignará IPs fuera del rango LAN y, por lo tanto, no tendrás problemas para comunicarte con las máquinas de ésta (sea cual sea la configuración de `client-to-client`).

Ahora debes agregar la ruta estática a la máquina Apache para que sepa cómo llegar a los clientes de la VPN de la siguiente manera:

```
ip route add 10.9.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.1
```

Una vez realizados estos cambios deberías tener conectividad bidireccional entre tu cliente de VPN y el servidor Apache.

La mejor herramienta para depurar problemas de enrutamiento de tráfico en redes IP es `traceroute`.

Para comprobar los saltos y la llegada correcta de los paquetes usa desde tu cliente VPN:

```
traceroute -n 10.8.0.3
```

Y desde tu servidor Apache puedes comprobar la ruta inversa con:

```
traceroute -n 10.9.0.2
```

La principal desventaja de este sistema es que, al no querer salida a Internet en el servidor Apache y no querer configurar una ruta por defecto, hay que agregar una ruta estática para que sepa cómo llegar a los clientes VPN.

## Solución propuesta (2)

Para no tener que agregar rutas estáticas en el servidor Apache se puede usar NAT para que los clientes VPN contacten con él usando la IP LAN del servidor VPN.

A la solución anterior (sin agregar ruta estática en el servidor Apache) habría que agregar la siguiente regla de `iptables` al servidor VPN:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

La principal desventaja de este sistema es que a los ojos del servidor Apache las conexiones las establece el servidor VPN, por lo que no podremos diferenciar de qué cliente VPN en particular es una conexión.

## Archivo de configuración final

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/vpn.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/vpn.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem
server 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb1
```

Comment: Buenas @OscarGarcia gracias por su respuesta tras realizar las diferentes modificaciones ocurre lo siguiente -- cuando hago traceroute -n 10.8.0.3 -- me sale en la primera trama: 10.8.0.1 339.235 ms 342.003ms 402.995 ms y ya en las sucesivas * (asteriscos) -- al hacer traceroute -n 10.9.0.2 en Apache me sale solo una trama que dice: 10.8.0.3 2998.471ms !H 2982.388ms 2982.353ms !H -- Y sigo sin verse cuando hago ping entre ellos

Comment: si hago ip route show en APACHE me aparece lo siguiente: 10.9.0.0/24 vía 10.8.0.1 dev enp0s8 -- y sí en VPN tengo tengo 10.9.0.2 y me hacen ping entre Apache y VPN, y entre VPN y cliente

Comment: traceroute to 10.9.0.1 -- me sale 10.8.0.3 2996.493 ms 2996.112 ms !H 2996.100 ms !H. hago ping 10.9.0.1 -- Destination host Unreachable. Mi cliente es cierto que esta en una LAN 192.168.1.x que al conectarme me da 10.9.0.6, al darle sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward tengo 1(es decir lo tengo activo) y he desactivado client-to-client y nada. Nose que más hacer

Comment: Disculpa, no te he vuelto a escribir por que está solucionado a medias... hacen ping entre los diferentes equipos todo perfecto, pero cuando intentamos acceder a la web desde el cliente VPN no accede, cuando desconectamos el VPN termina de cargar, pero mientrastanto está siempre como en un continuo intento de acceder a la web, en ocasiones anteriores esto no nos ha ocurrido

Comment: Yo he ido paso por paso de lo que me ha indicado

Comment: Si si , disculpa @OscarGarcia ha sido después de introducir la NAT

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para conversaciones extensas.
 [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65502/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-ramon-devesa).